# How to force Babel to perform a transformation?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I have the following files:

```
./client/.babelrc
./client/index.js
./server/.babelrc
./server/index.js
```

#### Client

`./client/index.js` code is:

```js
import 'test';
```

`./client/.babelrc` is:

```json
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015-webpack",
        "stage-0",
        "react"
    ]
}
```

Client code is consumed by webpack 2. webpack 2 [supports ES6 modules](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html). [`es2015-webpack`](https://github.com/gajus/babel-preset-es2015-webpack) is a babel preset that transforms code down to ES5, but does not transform ES6 modules to CommonJS. Therefore, the transpiled code remains unchanged.

#### Server

`./server/index.js` code is:

```js
import './../client';
```

`./server/.babelrc` is:

```json
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "stage-0"
    ]
}
```

node.js v5.5.0 does not support ES6 modules. Therefore, the entire code needs to be transpiled down to ES5. However, node script needs to include parts of the client code (e.g., config, initial state).

I try to run server code using `babel-node`, e.g.

```
cd ./server
babel-node ./index.js
```

This produces an error:

```
./client/index.js:1
import 'test';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

The reason it does this is because `babel-node` (and `babel`) respect `./client/.babelrc`.

How do I force Babel to use `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` plugin (or `es2015` preset) for the entire code base when compiling server code?

I have tried using `--no-babelrc` option. But it only ignores `.babelrc` in the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Have just been working on a similar problem

I ended up removing all the presets from [[.babelrc](https://github.com/djeeg/example-react-router-server-rendering-lazy-routes/blob/master/.babelrc)]

Adding the client presets via webpack [[webpack.config.js](https://github.com/djeeg/example-react-router-server-rendering-lazy-routes/blob/master/webpack.config.js)]

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loader: 'babel-loader', 
        query: { presets: ["react", "es2015-webpack"] } }
    ]
  },
```

And running the server presets via [[babel-node](https://github.com/djeeg/example-react-router-server-rendering-lazy-routes/blob/master/package.json)]

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=development; webpack --progress && babel-node --presets es2015,react modules/server.js"
  },
```